# Authentication service keeps returning same user ID

Tags: angular

My Authentication service keeps returning the same userID even when entering different username and password combinations

The endpoint has been checked with postman and seems to be working fine.

My authentication service is as follows

```
  authUser(user: UserAuth): Promise<any> {
    const url = `${this.baseURL}/Users/Authenticate`;
    return this.http.post<any>(url, user).toPromise()
      .then(payload => {
        return Promise.resolve(payload);
      })
  }
```

The method on my sign-in component that calls the service is as follows

```
authenticate() {
    this.user.username = this.username;
    this.user.password = this.password;
    this.userService.authUser(this.user)
      .then(
        res => {
          console.log(">>> Response:", this.response);
          this.response = res;
          if (this.response != null) {
            console.log(this.response)
            this.user.ID = this.response;
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
            this.uService.setUserID(this.user.ID);
          }
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      )
  }
```

The authenticate method is called on the login button (click)

Backend User object is in (asp.net MVC)

```
[BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Initials")]
        public string Initials { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Cell")]
        public string Cell { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Tel")]
        public string Tel { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Created")]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("ProfileImage")]
        public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Password")]
```

Comment: what is the responses you get? do they contains different user ids? Also can you post code for the user object

Comment: @Reeyaazh Why are you returning another promise again..? Here:- `return Promise.resolve(payload);` instead of just returning the actual payload..!

Comment: I get a 200 response when hitting the authenticate endpoint. , No the responses contain the same user ID . I will add the user code above

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Observable and Subscriptions methods when responding from a server? This will solve your problem with promis not carrying a payload in itself!